# When I press and hold volume down button with screen off, the phone beeps twice. How do I disable it?

Tags: audio, voice-recognition, huawei-honor-6

When I press and hold the volume down button on Huawei Honor 6, it beeps two times, even if the device is in silent mode. Between the beeps I see logcat message like this:

```
D/VARecorder(13631): RecorderThread XXXXXXXXXRECOGNIZER_LOCAL dataRead1200
...
02-13 03:45:08.630 D/SoundManager(16318): playRecognitionStopSound()
```

I suppose it looks like some voice command feature. How do I disable this (or at least its beeps)?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: moving away `/system/priv-app/HwVAssistant.*` disabled the feature.

Similar feature of pressing double volume-down => taking insta-photo persisted.